# I am using angular-ui's typeahead to autocomplete data from an API

Tags: javascript, angularjs, angular-ui-bootstrap

I am using angular UI's typeahead to get data from an API, the problem is the dataset is too huge and makes the browser hang for a considerable amount of time. The API has around 20,000 objects of JSON data and for instance searching for "p" would require at least transfer of 1.4 MB of data. Please help me sort out the issue.

The UI code is:

```
<input type="text" class="form-control" ng-model="drug_name" ng-change="searchDrug()" placeholder="Search Drug" uib-typeahead="drug as drug.display_name for drug in drug_full_name" typeahead-loading="loadingRecipients" typeahead-no-results="noResults" />
                                    <i ng-show="loadingRecipients" class="glyphicon glyphicon-refresh"></i>
                                    <div ng-show="noResults">
                                        <i class="glyphicon glyphicon-remove"></i>No Results Found
                                    </div>
```

and the function that is fired to search the data is

```
$scope.searchDrug = function() {
        $scope.showSpinner = 1;

        var dataList = document.getElementById('alldrugs');
        //search drug from rxnorm database
        $http({

            method: 'POST',
            url: 'http://104.155.102.226:8033/getdrug/',
            data: {
                "brand_name":$scope.drug_name
            },
            headers: {
                'accept':'application/json',
                'Content-Type':'application/json'
            }

        }).success(function(data){
            console.log(data);
            for(var i = 0; i< data.length; i++) {
              $scope.drug_brand_name = data[i].display_name
            }
           var drug_full_name = data; 


           $scope.drug_full_name = data;


        }).error();
```

Answer (score 0):

Your API on the server should limit the number of objects that it sends back to a sensible amount, such as 10. Your users won't need to scroll through 20000 autocomplete suggestions.